# MongoDB 3.4 - How to add config servers to a mongos

Tags: mongodb, replication, database-replication, sharding

I'm editting the config file of a mongos. And I have a replicaSet of n config servers. To balance the load among all of them, I have to write all config servers in the config file, or it's enough to add the master?

```
sharding:
  configDB: <configReplSetName>/cfg1.example.net:27017, cfg2.example.net:27017,...
```

The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#sharding.configDB) is not very clear about this. Thank you.

**Edit - Possible solution**: I've found [this doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/troubleshoot-sharded-clusters/#a-config-server-replica-set-member-become-unavailable), where I interpret, that you should add all your config servers to your mongo's config file. Otherway, if the master config server cannot be accessed, the cluster won't be able to operate. This makes sense, since, in mongodb architecture, only mongos can act as load balancers. If someone can confirm this, I will vote him.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's enough to add master". Please rephrase your question.

Comment: Sorry, I've extended the description a bit.